# PHP function for auto increment with changed value

Tags: php, function, for-loop, auto-increment

I have a requirement where I need to insert `user_id` in following format

```
13310_userid_1
13310_userid_2
13310_userid_3
```

where

```
13310 = $_GET['userid'] //user id from session
userid = constant //constant text defined
1/2/3 = autoincrement value
```

Here the variation is when `user_id` is changed, the auto increment value will be inserted from beginning which would look like

```
13311_userid_1
13311_userid_2
13311_userid_2
```

and not

```
13311_userid_4
13311_userid_5
13311_userid_6
```

How can I check if the `user_id` is changed and insert auto increment value from `1` ?

Thanks

Comment: in what you will instert this?(DB, array ...)

Comment: where do you store all the data? anyway, you just want to loop through your data, split it a string with _ in the last item, and get the last value of it. If it is 3, then reset your counter to 1.

Comment: @lolka_bolka yes you are close, and the data will be inserted as primary key for `user_id` column. But how to loop this considering change of `user_id` ?

Comment: Is `$_GET['user_id']` an array or does it come through as a single value on each request? If the former, simply compare the current value against the previous and increment/reset as required. If the latter, you'll need to store the value somewhere (DB?) and compare it.

Comment: `$_GET['user_id']` is not an array but a single value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it's that you need, but you can use an array to store increment of each cont :

```
$const = 'userid';
$user_id = '13310';
$array_increment[$user_id] =1;
foreach(array('Franck','Robert','You','Me') as $index=>$test){
    if($index==2)$user_id = '13311';
    if(!isset($array_increment[$user_id])){
        $array_increment[$user_id]=1;
    }

    $increment = $array_increment[$user_id];

    echo $user_id.'_'.$const.'_'.$increment.'<br />';
    $array_increment[$user_id]++;
}
```

Will show :

```
13310_userid_1
13310_userid_2
13311_userid_1
13311_userid_2
```

Comment: We do not need to change the constant here, but to change incremented value if the `$_GET['user_id']` is changed.

Comment: `$_GET['user_id']` is not an array but a single value. Once this val is changed from `13310` to `13311`, auto increment number will reset and counter will be set to 1 again.

Comment: Same thing, in your case you have to store $array_increment somewhere (bdd, txt, xml) and read value to continue your incrementation

Comment: What does this `if($index==2)$user_id = '13311';` line specifies and what I need to pass instead of `array('Franck','Robert','You','Me')` ?
`$_GET['user_id']` will be a single value.

Comment: Number will be auto incremented only when `$_GET['user_id']` is changed from `13310` to `13311`.

Comment: `if($index==2)$user_id = '13311';` simulate $_GET['user_id'] change , in your case it s $_GET['user_id'] who change.
This array is only for demonstration, u dont have to do a loop in your case.

Answer (score 0):

you could store the incremental value of each userid in a temporary session:

For each request check if $_GET['userid'] already exists in a session if not create it with value zero.
Increment by one and use this value to create your string for inserting into DB

```
    //set up session if it is not already set


    if(!isset($_SESSION['users'][$_GET['userid'])){
    $_SESSION['users'][$_GET['userid']=0;
    }

    $_SESSION['users'][$_GET['userid']=$_SESSION['users'][$_GET['userid']+1;
    $user=$_GET['userid'].'_userid_'.$_SESSION['users'][$_GET['userid'];


   //insert $user into your DB or permanent storage.
   $db->insert($user);
```

Comment: Number will be auto incremented only when `$_GET['user_id']` is changed from 13310 to 13311

Comment: why do you say that ? The number will increment each time whether or not the id is different. The line which includes the increment is not in any condition.

Answer (score 0):

(this should be a comment but its a bit verbose)

Your only makes sense if a database figures in here somewhere - but you never explicitly stated that this is the case nor which database it is.

Relational database design (and to quite a large extent, non-relational database design) is subject to the rules of normalization. These are methods for describing the structure of your data and prevent you doing stupid things. This **breaks the first rule**.

Assuming you were designing the system properly, then you would keep the three attributes as seperate fields. But that does not answer the question of whether the id is nominal, cardinal or ordinal (and in the case of ordinal numbers whether there is a requirement for them to be consecutive).